# Will we get a better IRI implemtationn, which use less CPU/RAM?

Tags: iri-node, node, cpu

Will we get a better IRI implemtationn, which use less CPU/RAM?

Question in the title.

Comment: I think you want to know about libs for IOT devices. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, the nodes get bored as soon as they're synchronized.

```
Load average: 0.12 0.11 0.09
Uptime: 3 days, 21:07:04
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call a C++ IRI "better", but more memory efficient. And yes there are more IRI implementations planned, like Go or C#. A real boost will be provided by the Curl-P algorithm. This will make POW faster and more efficient.
Just check the Roadmap:[Roadmap](https://blog.iota.org/iota-development-roadmap-74741f37ed01)